# vue.js javascript expression in href

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

EDIT: Answered, increment and decrement changed the values. '#' + (post.id+1) and '#' + (post.id-1) do not, thansk [blex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913729/blex).

I have a series of id'ed divs that I want to navigate to the next one and the previous one through links.

Using vue.js, I want to put in a JavaScript expression in the href to add one to the current id to function as a "next" button, and have another link that subtracts one from the current id to function as a "previous" button.

Here is my HTML, where I have a Vue Component:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="blog-post-demo" class="demo">
  <blog-post
    v-for="post in posts"
    v-bind:key="post.id"
    v-bind:post="post"
  ></blog-post>
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript, where I make the component and template:

```
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['post'],
  template: `
    <div class="blog-post" v-bind:id="post.id">
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
      <div v-html="post.body"></div>
      <a :href="'#' + post.id--">Previous Entry</a>
      <a :href="'#' + post.id++">Next Entry</a>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#blog-post-demo',
  data: {
    posts: []
  },
  created: function () {
    // Alias the component instance as `vm`, so that we  
    // can access it inside the promise function
    var vm = this
    // Fetch our array of posts from an API
    fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1bjyk2')
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        vm.posts = data
      })
  }
})
```

Right now, I'm using increment and decrement operators to change the values, but no such luck.

What doesn't work is that the "Next Entry" link goes back two, and the "Previous Entry" link goes to the same id. How can I fix this? Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pakfhegw/) that I've been working on, originally from the Vue.js components tutorial.

Comment: Doing `post.id--` or `post.id++` actually changes the value of `post.id`. Just do `'#' + (post.id-1)` and `'#' + (post.id+1)` Note: the parentheses are important here, otherwise, it will add the string `"1"` to the `href`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly